# Application not respond on tomcat after abour 30min on c3p0 configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have a problem with c3p0. Last time I configured c3p0 as dataSource in application because Quartz Scheduler opened new connection for every check, now is ok but from this time application doesnt respond after about 30mins, sometimes more. There is no logs  in catalina or application logs file. Other applications work normally on the same server. On this application I got 404. I returned to default Spring data source and removed configuration and everything works.

What can cause the problem ?

`Tomcat 8.0.21 
 c3p0.version 0.9.5.1
 Hibernate version 4.3.1.Final`

Configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- HIBERNATE CONFIGURATION -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</prop>

            <!-- HIBERNATE SEARCH CONFIGURATION -->
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${hibernate.search.local}</prop>

            <!-- CONNECTIONS POOLING CONFIGURATION -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">60</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Update with new settings:

```
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">60</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</prop>
```

Still same, one user,  1h:40min

Comment: Change your timeout value, your pool is getting exhausted.

Comment: Did you try changing the values??

Comment: Yes I tried before, and I changed yesterday too and I'm waiting for effect now

Comment: Change max statement to 100,  and your timeout is too high, set it to 30.